# GRANT EXECUTE for "sp_delete_database_backuphistory" for group of users

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, roles

I have a group login which has the Server Role "dbcreator". Users of this login has been granted execute on "sp_delete_database_backuphistory" so that they can delete each others databases. The problem now is that it is possible for these users to delete databases created by other logins. Is there a solution for this? Can permission´s be set, so that these users **ONLY** can delete databases created with this login?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly, but you can wrap the system sp_delete_database_backuphistory into your own usp_delete_database_backuphistory
that can call sp_delete_database_backuphistory or return immediately depending on a result of the check you want to perform. 
I cannot ask you in a comment what do you mean saying 'databases created by other users', first of all only login (not user) can create a database but this information (db creator) you cannot extract from any system metadata, all you can get is the current database owner and this can differ from database creator.
I mean, when you create a database you can explicitly assign other login to own the database, or you can do this later for certain purposes

Comment: Hi sepupic :). I have modified the original text so that there are no confusion to what im trying to achieve here. I will try to look into to your suggestion and see if this is the solution im looking for. Thank you

Comment: Hi Peter, I repeat the problem: a database has no idea who has created it, this information is not memorized in database metadata; the only thing you can check is the OWNER of database, and the owner can be set to any login.I have one server where the owner of all the databases is sa but sa account is disabled at all, what should your code do in such a case? No one could ever delete backup history?